# Convert string to IntPtr

Tags: sendmessage

sorry about my English is poor.
I convert string to IntPtr using

```
COPYDATASTRUCT cd = new COPYDATASTRUCT();
            cd.dwData = 0;

            cd.lpData = Marshal.StringToHGlobalAuto(Msg).ToInt32();
            cd.cbData = Msg.Length;
  Marshal.StringToHGlobalAuto(Msg);
```

and send it to another window using SendMessage method 
When i receive it and read the IntPtr as string using

```
COPYDATASTRUCT CD = (COPYDATASTRUCT)Marshal.PtrToStructure(lParam, typeof(COPYDATASTRUCT));
 byte[] B = new byte[CD.cbData]; 
IntPtr lpData = new IntPtr(CD.lpData);
string temp = Marshal.PtrToStringUni(lpData);
Marshal.Copy(lpData, B, 0, CD.cbData);
string strData = Encoding.Default.GetString(B);
```

i receive this data
M\0S\0G\0!\0@\01\0|\01\0|\0C\0:\0\\0U\0s\0e\0r\0s\0\\0f\0.\0a\0l\0s\0a\0

When i make strData.Replace("\0","")

i receive my message but it is truncated.
MSG!@1|1|C:\Users\f.alsa

original message is MSG!@1|1|C:\Users\f.alsayyed\Desktop\File.ktb

Answer (score 0):

To me it looks like your replace function found a zero termination earlier then where string ends, as it seems your received data contains zero's inside the string too.